# php inside html. syntax issues.

Tags: javascript, php, html, insert

I need help with inserting php inside html. 
I have the below which causes me a javascript error.

The error being: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Can anyone help? Thanks

`<a href="javascript:fin(<?php echo $character['addresses'][$i]; ?>) style="width:100%; height:100%;">`

Comment: Strings in javascript need to be quoted, ie `"some string"`, if your `$character['addresses'][$i]` is a string you didn't quote it

Comment: The `href=` is missing the terminating double-quote character.

Comment: If I quote the string I get a parse error.

Comment: Show the rendered output that will give you more clues on what is going on. You have to do both corrections, use the end quote for the `href="..."` and quote the php output

Answer (score -1):

You aren't closing your href property. Just add the closing double-quotes after your javascript parentheses. See the code below:

```
<a href="javascript:fin(<?php echo $character['addresses'][$i]; ?>)" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help however closing the tag makes no difference, exactly the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Very strange, but an error within my javascript function cause the issue. I made a typo on a window.close call, I had put window..close by mistake.

Not sure why this would cause this error however I am also assuming that not closing the a href tag correctly would have caused a further error after correcting my double ..

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Problems caused by typos are off-topic because they are unlikely to help future visitors. You can delete this answer and then delete the question, to save it spending time in the review queues.